# Python | Reading JSON files and applying simple algorithm on each iteratively into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, machine-learning

we have a large json file that takes too long to be read with pd.read_json.

What we want to do initially is :

```
# Load the file
df_view = pd.read_json('/path/to/file', lines=True)

# Create a new feature using the above dataframe
df_nb_view = df_view[['userid','itemid']]
df_nb_view = df_nb_view.groupby('userid').count()
df_nb_view.rename(index=str, columns = {"itemid":'item_viewed'}, inplace=True)
```

So I've divided the dataset into subsets of it in one folder, and would like to read iteratively into it so as to do the work above on each subset, and concatenating the result at each step.

Hope this is clear enough.

I started out with this so as to read each file into one final df, but not sure how to create the new features in the process.

```
files = []
for file in os.listdir("/path/to/folder"):
    if file.endswith(".json"):
        files.append(os.path.join("/path/to/folder", file))

for file in files:
    with codecs.open(file,'r','utf-8') as f:
        df_view = json.load(f, encoding='utf-b')
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to read and process in file chunks.
If so, create a final result dataframe and append to it in each iteration

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()

for filename in files:
    df_view = pd.read_json(filename, lines=True)
    df_nb_view = df_view[['userid','itemid']]
    df_nb_view = df_nb_view.groupby('userid').count()
    df_nb_view.rename(index=str, columns = {"itemid":'item_viewed'}, inplace=True)    

    final_df.append(df_nb_view)
```